# Sitecore 9.3.0 installation error. Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (2)

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-assistant

When I try to install **Sitecore 9.3.0** with **Sitecore Install Assistant** I got an error:

```
[------------- XConnectXP0_CleanShards : Command -----------------------------]
[ShardingTool - Clean]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore93xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe
Command C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore93connect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (2)
[TIME] 00:03:20
Command C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitecore93xconnect.dev.local\App_Data\collectiondeployment\Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (2)
```

Sitecore databases *(master, web, etc.)* were created successfully. I can see them in `SSMS`.
I have **SQL Server 2017**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was resolved by replacing `double backslashes` in **Microsoft SQL Server instance** value with `single backslash`:

[image]

It seems that issue is with slashes escaping. Single and double backslashes both work fine in `powershell` *(because of this you can see some created sitecore databases)*, but double backslash does not work in `Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Database.SqlShardingDeploymentTool.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing Sitecore 10 and I managed to fix this by removing reference of "Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom" from GAC using gacutil.

Worth to mention that my Sitecore 9.3 installation was smooth for me and I didn't remove ScriptDOM from to GAC to make that work.

As you mentioned you got this fixed by removing the slash in the instance name, but in my case I didn't had any slash in the instance name.

Below screenshot shows the error I got while installing Sitecore 10 using SIA.

[image]

Wanted to share this as this might help others.